# Intermittent Issue with SCAN_Enable error on app load

Tags: windows-ce, motorola-emdk

I acquired a batch of WT0490 wearable pdas with detachable scan head, so converted an application originally made for Windows Mobile (which has been running perfectly for several years) to run on the WT4090s. The devices use these versions:

- Windows CE 5.0
- EMDK 2.6
- ASP.net CF 2.0

Since rollout I've seen some very frustrating behaviour, which seems to start happening after the devices have been operating a few days. Users are reporting the following error:

Unexpected error in application

SCAN_Enable

There doesnt seem to be any noticeable pattern, several devices will be working perfectly for a few days then suddenly this error will show. THen a few days and a few reboots later they work again.

All devices were taken right back to stock settings then our cabs deployed to them. All identical models. We've tried altering memory allocation, swapping scanner headers etc but there is no pattern.

The error seems to occur on load of the first form after login, the login screen displays a list of users in a dropdown with a password box so that part of the app works ok, it seems to be when the scanner is initialised that this failure happens.

I had 40 devices, now 30+ have gone down with this same issue so my gut is telling me its a software issue but as yet ive not been able to find out why.

We've tried warm boots, cold boots, complete reprovisionings as well. We have a couple of dev units that don't show the problem although they are not in regular use so maybe we just haven't seen the problem 'yet'.

I hope someone out there has had this issue and knows how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

WT4090 was built by Motorola Solution enterprise business, now part of Zebra Technologies. The WT4090 is currently in EOS (End Of Sales) but is still supported by Zebra if you've a maintenance contract.

You can check if you've the latest OS version and fixes installed on the device looking on [Zebra Technologies support website](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Mobile+Computers/Wearable+Computers/WT4000_US-EN).

For question on how to develop for Zebra Technologies devices you can take a look at [Launchpad](https://developer.motorolasolutions.com/community/technologies/mobile_computing), Zebra's developer community website.

Answer (score 1):

It's Worth noting that these devices have detachable barcode scanners - so if the scanner is not correctly attached, you get a SCAN_Enable error.

If you don't release the scanner, you can also see this error as a previous form could have the scanner blocked.

You may also find you have the ScanWedge app running - this will also block the scanner so you cannot get it enabled. The EMDK needs exclusive access to the scanner to enable it.